# Why there's unwanted white rectangle when we perform view slide up animation

Tags: android, animation

Currently, I perform a footer view slide up animation, by using the following technique.

```
// Start the animation.
ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(view).setStartDelay(2000).setDuration(2000).translationY(0).alpha(1.0f).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator animation) {
        ViewHelper.setTranslationY(view, view.getHeight());
        ViewHelper.setAlpha(view, 0.0f);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator animation) {
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator animation) {

    }
});
```

The XML for the layout is as following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:requiresFadingEdge="none"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/default_tab_layout_height"
            android:clipToPadding="false" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/default_tab_layout_height"
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/not_found_linear_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone" >
                <TextView android:textColor="?attr/dimForeground" android:textSize="44sp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/sorry" />
                <TextView android:textColor="?attr/dimForeground" android:textSize="16sp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/no_buy_data_found" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/touch_delegate_linear_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer_linear_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="?attr/buyPortfolioFooterLinearLayoutBackground"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/footer_label_text_view"
                android:text="@string/buy_portfolio_value"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:textColor="?attr/buyPortfolioFooterTextViewColor"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:background="?attr/buyPortfolioFooterTextViewSelector" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:background="?attr/buyPortfolioFooterDividerColor" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/footer_value_text_view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:textColor="?attr/buyPortfolioFooterTextViewColor"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ff000000"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextSwitcher
                android:id="@+id/status_bar"
                android:width="0dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/currency_exchange_linear_layout"
                android:background="?attr/buyPortfolioCurrencyExchangeLinearLayoutSelector"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:width="0dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextSwitcher
                    android:id="@+id/currency_exchange_rate_text_switcher"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/to_currency_text_view"
                    android:textColor="?attr/buyPortfolioStatusBarTextViewColor"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <TextSwitcher
                    android:id="@+id/currency_pair_text_switcher"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The animation is being performed on `footer_linear_layout`

Here's is the outcome of the animation - https://youtu.be/r1zQKpj2HVo

As you can see, when the bottom footer view being slide up, there is an unwanted white rectangle.

Any idea where the white rectangle comes from? May I know how I can avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

Because there was nothing underneath the footer.  So when it slid down, you got a blank area.  To avoid that you'd need data under there, or you'd need to do a grow followed by a shrink on the content above.  If you want to do that I'd seriously look into CoordinatorLayout to ease some of the work

Comment: I do a quick work, to replace the root `LinearLayout` to `CoordinatorLayout`. However, the outcome isn't promising - http://i.imgur.com/UbDsGRU.png Is this because, I should define some custom behavior for `CoordinatorLayout`? Sorry, I'm not familiar with `CoordinatorLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing the view was `GONE` before animation started? And on starting animation `view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` made Android create space for it and made the other view smaller (`FrameLayout` in your case as it has weight 1 and height 0). You'd have to make `footer_linear_layout` overlap with the `FrameLayout` to get rid of the space. Maybe move that view inside the `FrameLayout` or something like that